# tmux won't display 12 hour time

Tags: tmux

I've set the `clock-mode-style` option to use 12 hour time in my `.tmux.conf`, as described in [the manpages](https://man.cx/tmux(1)):

```
set-window-option -g clock-mode-style 12
```

I then saved my changes and reloaded my config using `:source-file ~/.tmux.conf`, but the clock still shows in 24 hour time:

[image: tmux clock using 24 hour time]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`clock-mode-style` and `clock-mode-colour` are the two options for the  `clock-mode` window.
As an example [here's a blog about this mode](http://blog.yjl.im/2011/02/tmux-clock-mode-as-working-pain.html).

To achieve what you want (having a 12 hours clock in the status bar) you should change the status bar config in your tmux configuration to something like:

```
set -g status-right "#[fg=cyan]%A, %d %b %Y %I:%M %p"
```

tmux uses `strftime` to configure it's status line:

> **status-right** *string*
>   Display string to the right of the status bar. By default, the current window title in double quotes, the date and the time are shown. As with status-left, string will be passed to [`strftime(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime), character pairs are replaced, and UTF-8 is dependent on the status-utf8 option.

you can use @mbuckbee's ["For a Good `strftime`" website](http://foragoodstrftime.com) to play with the configuration.